# SLRE regex doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, regex

I have a problem with SLRE library, I can't figure out how to stop grabbing everything after my match. Let's say I have a html output and somewhere in the middle of buffer there is line I want to parse

```
name="id" value="1a2b3c4d5e6f" />
```

Here is my regular expression

```
slre_compile(&test, "name=\"id\" value=\"(.*?)\" />")
```

I have read about greedy and non-greedy flags in other threads where people used to have similar problem as me, but in my case adding *?* to the expression doesn't change anything.
SLRE returns me match starting from `1a2b3c4d5e6f" />` and shows rest of the html page ending on `</html>` tag, just I don't know why. It is cutting the beginning of the html source but leaves everything after my expression. I have also tried following regex

```
slre_compile(&test, "^.*?name=\"id\" value=\"(.*?)\" />.*?$")
```

and some others, modified with greedy and non-reedy flags, which gave me same results. Does anyone know why SLRE can't stop at `" />` and continues capturing characters till the source string ends?

Comment: How does `value=\"[^\"]*\"` work?

Comment: @m.buettner it matches nothing, 0 bytes
should I change the regex library to something more reliable?

Comment: I don't know SLRE, so I don't know whether that's the issue. Try replacing `\" />` with `\"\\s*/>` as well. Maybe there's a mismatch with your whitespace.

Comment: @m.buettner still captures unnecessary html code after matched value

Comment: No. Stop! Read the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Now! Don't do this!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that SLRE does not understand non-greedy qualifiers and parses `.*?` instead as if it were `(?:.*)?`. However, in this case `\"[^\"]*\"` should work...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is also matching wanted value and rest of the page. Too bad, I though SLRE would be a perfect native crossplatform library but it seems it lacks some standard features or I'm just too stupid for this and I'm doing something completely wrong.